# How do I rationalize a relational model with too many cross-references and optional foreign keys?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I am trying to keep my data model sane, but it appears to have too many references across. Here are the relevant entities

- User
- Event
- Series (group of Events)
- Signup (for an Event)
- Registration (for a Series)
- Transaction (all User charges and payments)

A User signs up for an Event, which creates a Signup. Because they signed up, a charge is automatically created on their account, i.e. a Transaction. An Event may also be part of a Series (of Events), or standalone. A User also can register for a Series, which creates a Registration, automatically leading to a different charge Transaction. They can also be tied together, e.g. if the User registers for a Series and pays $100 up front, they get a 20% discount on the price of each event.

- User N:M Event (via Signup)
- User N:M Series (via Registration)
- Event N:1 Series (optional; Event can stand alone)
- Transaction N:1 Event
- Transaction N:1 Signup
- Transaction N:1 Series
- Transaction N:1 Registration

But Signup is already tied to an Event! So is the Transaction:Event FK a waste? On the one hand, the Signup is the "cause" of the Transaction, so it should be included. On the other, the Transaction is tied directly to the Event. We want to be able to search on Transactions for a particular Event, rather than by Signup. But we also want to be able to search by Signup.

Similarly, Registration is already tied to Series, so is the Transaction:Series FK a waste?

And, of course, a Transaction could be tied to *either* a Series+Registration *or* an Event+Signup, but not both. Requiring one pair or the other is an unholy mess.

Making it more complex, there are other entities like Series and Game that a Transaction could be tied to, and a Transaction is tied to an Event+Signup *or* a Series+Registration, but not both.

The current model is visualized as follows (EDIT: made it cleaner).

[image]

UPDATE:
@GertArnold helped clarify the question in the comments. I have two distinct issues:

1. The linkage between Tx and Series+Registration for some Tx, and Event+Signup for others, means that it is a messy foreign key relationship. If I can link a Tx to other resources, it is even more of a mess.
2. The redundancy of linking Tx to Event *and* Signup, since a Signup can only exist in the context of a single Event.

These are both issues making it messy. @GertArnold suggested removing the Signup *and* Event redundancy. My reluctance was because sometimes a Signup can cause multiple Tx and charges. For example, if an Event is part of a Series, and the Series has a one-time fee on it (first time you Signup for an Event in that Series, you get charged):

- Charge the Event cost as a Tx because you Signup
- Charge the Series one-time fee as a Tx because this is the first Signup in the Series

Future Signup for this Series only will incur the Event cost.

As long as the Tx was linked to Event or Series, I could easily distinguish. If I link Tx to Signup, how do I enter the Series one-time fee when I Signup for an Event that is part of a Series? It is a Series charge caused by an Event's Signup?

I must be making this too messy with a bad data model. How should this be cleaned up?

UPDATE: Signup vs Registration

As @Jay suggested, I could combine Signup and Registration into one, and then have Transaction FK to the now-unified Signup. But then a Signup could link to an Event or a Series, and my FK N:1 Signup:Event and Registration:Series becomes FK N:1 Signup:(Event||Series), and the messiness in Tx, which I am trying to solve, just gets pushed to the Signup.

There is an additional difference between Signup and Registration. When I Signup for an Event, it is done. When I Register for a Series, I *must* enforced by required FK Subscription, pick a Subscription, which is the "package". Think of it like a bunch of concerts (Events). I could Signup for a single concert, or I could Register for the Series (which has 10 concerts/Events). When I Register for the Series, I pick from Registration options (Subscriptions) the Series admin has provided:

- Pay $100 upfront for 50% off all concerts
- Pay $500 upfront for 100% off all concerts
- something else

Keeping Registration separate from Signup enables me both to have a required FK Registration:Series and a required FK Registration:Subscription.

UPDATE: Transaction vs Registration vs Signup

@Jay/@HLGEM asked why I cannot eliminate Tx entirely. Registration and Signup logically represent the connection between a User and Series or Event, respectively.

Transaction represents financial impacts: charges, payments or credits. A User registering for his/her first Event might see:

1. User Signup for Event
2. User gets a Tx of type "charge" for the Event (e.g. $75)
3. User gets a Tx of type "charge" for the Series (e.g. everyone Signing up for an Event in the Series has to pay a one-time $20 fee; this is common in my use cases)
4. User pays for the Event ($95 in our case)
5. User gets a Tx of type "payment"
6. User's balance on account (sum of all Tx) is now $0 (-$75 + -$20 + +$20)

In the above example - which is a very common use case for us - there are 3 Transactions:

- -$75 for the Event caused by the Signup
- -$20 for the Series caused by the Signup
- $95 caused by the payment

So I can have:

- Tx connected to an Event solely through a Signup
- Tx connected to a Series solely through a Registration
- Tx connected to a Series not through a Registration, e.g. caused by a Signup but not directly tied to the Signup
- Tx not connected to any Event or Series, e.g. a payment

It is entirely possible I just have such a mess of potential relationships that this is the best I can do... but a lot of people smarter than me on this forum who probably could look and say, "no, you fool, do it this way." (no offense will be taken; I promise)

Comment: I guess that this depends on whether the redundant FKs are critical for read performance.

Comment: @GertArnold you mean, as opposed to just doing a join through Signup? It would not be too hard to build that query. That would eliminate possible strange situations, like having a valid Signup and Series, when Signup+Event is the valid combo. My whole thing still feels so very messy.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Less joins is always faster (although the difference may be insignificant). But if possible, always prevent redundancies.

Comment: Agreed, although this may be a valid use case for the extra join. I think you have helped me clarify that there really are multiple issues here. One is the redundancy (Signup+Event); the other is the linkage between Tx and Signup+Event in some Tx, and Registration+Series in others. If I have more than just Series and Event, it gets even messier. I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: Updated. You really are helping clarify the problem. Now I need to understand the answer. I know I have overcomplicated it, just don't know how to simplify it.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a logical data model, rather than a conceptual data model.  If I'm right, this means that we may be able to tell you whether your design is right or wrong, but not whether your analysis of the subject matter is right or wrong.  Do you have an ER model of this subject, as oposed to a relational model like the one you have presented?  In particular, are some of the tables you have presented as entities really relationships, and not entities?  The distinction is moot in a relational model, but not in an ER model.

Comment: @WalterMitty that isn't a bad idea. I will put one together. I tend to think in logical relational models, which probably is my own weakness.

Comment: Thinking in terms of relational models is not a weakness.  It's just that you need to do the analysis before you begin the design.  (Sometimes the analyis is unavoidably incomplete).  I think that an ER model is better for analysis and a relational one for design.

Comment: For dtabase 101 problems, the analysis is often so trivial that you can do it in your head.  In the real world, not so much.

Comment: @WalterMitty true! Story of every technology I have ever looked at. The 101 problems somehow don't relate to the real world.

Comment: Drat. I have been using MySQL Workbench on Mac for drawing Crow's Feet diagrams, but it doesn't support other models. I will try to draw it up on OmniGraffle

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that there are too many relationships, but that there are relationships that appear to be redundant. If table X is logically related to 10 other tables, that may just be how it is. I wouldn't change a design just because there were too many relationships, just like I wouldn't change a design just because there were too many integer fields, or too many tables with "w" in the name.

But that said: I got a little confused by your description. Maybe that's a symptom of the problem. But my thoughts:

If A relates to B and B relates to C, and the only way that A can relate to C is through B, then DON'T create a separate connection from A to C. Not initially, anyway. If you need to find the C that connects to a given A or vice versa, go through B. Otherwise you're repeating the same data, and creating the possibility for inconsistent data. Yes, this means that to connect A to C you have to do a 3 table join. But if that's the logical structure of the data, than that should be your initial design. If, in practice, this 3-table join is done all the time and it creates a performance problem, that MAY be a reason to de-normalize the database and put in redundant data. But don't start by denormalizing because you think something MIGHT turn out to be a problem if you do it by the textbook. It may well be that performance will be just fine and your screwing up your database for no good reason at all. And BTW, before I start denormalizing, I would look for whether I could solve the problem by creating a new index, or restructuring a query.

So by that reasoning: Can there ever be a Transaction for a Series that is not tied to a Registration? If not, then dump the connection from Transaction to Series. It appears to be redundant.

Likewise, can there ever be a Transaction for an Event without an associated Signup? If not, dump that FK. You say you need to find all the Transactions for an Event. Fine.

```
select tx_id, whatever 
from event j
oin signup on signup.event_id=event.event_id 
join tx on tx.signup_id=signup.signup_id 
where event_id=@eventid
```

That's a pretty straightforward query, no reason to be afraid of it.

What's the difference between a Registration and a Subscription? Why not just combine those into one table?

Maybe there's a lot more data that you're not showing here to try to simplify things. But I wonder: Do you even need 3 separate tables for Transaction, Signup, and Registration? Aren't Signup and Registration just two kinds of Transactions? Why not just combine all three into a single Transaction table, with a "transaction type" code that identifies whether it is a Signup, a Registration, or something else? Sure, this would mean that Transaction would have an event_id which is not relevant to Subscriptions and a series_id that is not relevant to Signups ... but it already has fields only relevant in one or the other case, so you're no worse off than before. (If there's a bunch of data that's not shown that's only relevant to one type of transaction or the other, the case for breaking this data out into separate tables is stronger.)

*Update*

Okay, here's how we did the system for doctor's offices:

There was a Tx table. This table had several types of transactions in it, but basically it came down to charges and payments. Charges were entered as positive numbers and payments as negative numbers. So when a patient visited the doctor, we created one or more Tx charge records. We created one for each service performed, like maybe $40 for "office visit" and $50 for "blood test" and $80 for "x-ray". Then when a patient paid, we created a Tx record for each payment. Current balance then was simply select sum(amount) from tx where patient_number=@pn.

Technically -- and maybe this is relevant to your case and maybe it isn't -- to save on having to process every transaction a patient ever had every time we wanted to know the balance, we actually created "zero balance" records in Tx every time the balance went to zero, and then we'd actually query for the last zero balance record, and then just retrieve records since then. This was also helpful when printing statements: a statement only included transactions since the last zero balance, and not going back potentially many years to the first time the patient visited the doctor.

So I'm not saying to create separate tables for charges and payments. Just create separate records within the Tx table. Maybe you need a "tx type" field to distinguish them. Though if the only types are charge and payment, the sign of the amount would distinguish them. Well, in your case it sounds like there are signups, registrations, and then something else that sometimes happens when a customer signs up. I don't quite follow how "making a payment to be in the series when he signs up for an event" is different from "registering for a series", but I suppose that's about how the organization works and how they bill people and so on. So make at least 4 Tx types: signup, registration, "something about a series that happens when you sign up", and payment. Maybe other things.

Comment: Jay and HLGEM, this really cuts to the heart of the issue, so thank you. This is what I was wrangling with. Doesn't answer everything, but tackles the core issues. There are some differences between a Registration and a Signup; updating the question with clarification now. Could I combine Signup and Registration? Sure, but then a Signup could link to an Event or a Series, and I have just moved my multiple FK (one or the other is required) into the Signup. Transactions, on the other hand, are financial. Updating to clarify that too. Love to see the additional feedback.

Comment: RE "but then a Signup could link to an Event or a Series". Sure. But now a Transaction can link to either an Event or a Series, so I don't see how you'd be any worse off. Perhaps I should clarify that I am not suggesting that the transaction for a signup and the transaction for a registration be combined. As I suspected, and as you have made clear is indeed the case in your update, there are still two distinct transactions here. I'm just saying that it may be that you could combine the two "things" into one table. Two records in that table, but both in the same table. But this is ...

Comment: ... really a side issue. If there is other data you need besides what you show here -- I think you've left out a bunch of detail to get to the point, which is fine -- then if there are more than a couple of fields that ONLY apply to a Signup or ONLY to a Registration, then combining all 3 into 1 table makes for a lot of dead fields, which can also be a problem. (Then someone trying to understand your code has to figure out which fields apply to which transaction types.)

Comment: right, which brings us back to the start. With Tx that apply to Event through Signup, and Tx that apply to Series through Registration, and Tx that apply to Series directly, etc. is there any way to better rationalize it than above?

Comment: Wait, let's say we accept that you need Signup, Registration, and Tx as separate tables. Still, you don't need Tx to link directly to Event or Series. If Tx links to Signup and Signup links to Event, then there is no need to also have Tx "bypass" Signup and link to Event directly. Same on the Series side.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of your first points and makes a lot of sense. But what happens if Signing up for an Event creates *two* Tx: one for the Event Signup, another for a Series one-time fee that kicks in the first time you Signup for any Event in the Series? (and a Series can be part of a Season, which itself can have a one-time fee, so then there are *three* Tx, etc.) I simplified the question a bit, but the idea of "Tx needs to connect to many different things, but one and only one at a time," is still there. I really am struggling.

Comment: Wondering if I shouldn't rename the question: how do I link my Tx to one and only one of Event, Series, Signup, Registration, Season, etc.

Comment: So 2 Tx's connect to the same Signup. It's a M:1 relationship. Just because 2 (or more) Tx's can connect to the same Signup doesn't mean that you then need to add a direct connection from Tx to Event. That doesn't help you at all. So a Tx can connect to one of 2 things: either a Signup or a Registration. As far as I can see, that's all you need. To make it connect to exactly 1 of those 2, you'd have to do that in code or with a trigger.

Comment: I wish! a Tx can connect to a Signup, or a Registration, or a Series (because someone Signed up which triggered a Series-related charge which was not a Registration), or a Season (same thing), or not connected at all, e.g. 1 Signup charge + 1 Series charge + 1 Season charge + 1 Signup charge for a different Event total $125 due, and someone has a single payment Tx of $125. A Tx can connect to one of at least 6 entities, and even no entity (e.g. arbitrary credit).

Comment: And, yeah, it can have 2 Tx on a single Signup. What if the Event is cancelled, and we reverse the charge with a credit? That is the original charge Tx and the reverse charge credit Tx.

Comment: If a Signup "generates" a Series-related charge, that sounds to me like it's a Signup-related charge, because you just said so. In which case the connection to Series is via Signup to Event to Series. Adding a separate link to Series creates redundant data.

Comment: If one payment can be for multiple things, and the implication here is that you want to keep track of that, then you need to distinguish Tx from "payment". At that point you probably need to distinguish the debits and credits. I worked on a few systems where customers did not necessarily pay cash on the barrelhead -- one for doctor's offices, where  you have to wait for insurance, then bill the patient for the difference. Another for furniture stores, where customers could make a down payment and then pay the rest off over time. In both cases, we made separate transactions for charges and ...

Comment: ... payments, and you had to add them up to find the customer's balance. In the case of the doctor's office, when a patient makes a payment, they don't necessarily say, This is for my visit on April 12, there could be multiple visits and multiple payments,  so it's all just one long running total. With the furniture stores we tied each payment to a specific purchase, so a payment Tx tied to a charge Tx (another link!).

Comment: RE reverse the charge, etc: That might create more complexity in the code -- more screens and so on -- but shouldn't really complicate the database. There can be more records in the table, but you don't need additional tables or fields. Well, maybe you need to tie the reversal to the original transaction.

Comment: Hold on, @Jay, I think you are onto something interesting. You are saying: a- even if a charge is Series-related, it came from a Signup (the actual action), so it should be Signup-connected. OK, how do I then tell that it is for this Series? If there are 2 Tx, how do I know which is for the Event price, which for the Signup one-time fee? b- Separating Tx from payment, so instead of single Tx entity you have multiple: TxCharge, TxPayment, TxCredit, etc. (i.e. 1 Debit type, 1 Credit type). I would still have the TxCharge to Signup vs Registration issue, but somewhat simplified.

Comment: Your doctor's office example sounds very close, at least in terms of charges for particular items, payments are just "to the account". Reversals actually would be tied to specific items, usually.

Comment: Can you update the answer to describe this? It is a *lot* closer to solving the issue. Thanks for the great input @Jay!

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you. I have something similar for Tx, with an "action" field (which is like your "type"). But how did you tie the Tx to each thing that happened? A particular blood tests (which is like my Event), or a particular office visit (like a Series), etc.?

Comment: To answer your q about "Tx in a Signup for a Series" different from Registration. User can Register for Series, which will create a Registration charge. User can also Signup for an Event, which will create a Signup charge. But a Series may have a one-time fee, first time a User signs up for any Event in Series, they get charged a one-time "Series fee". It just is the logic of the business. Series may be joined in Season, which has a one-time "Season fee", etc. So a single Signup can create an Event charge, and a Series charge, and a Season charge, etc. Make sense?